# Combining string and object as a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time finding the solution for this for some reason -- perhaps it's right under my nose.

But is there a way to essentially combine a string and an object so I'm not repeating the same method on a certain event?

```
$j(window).resize(function(){
  //stuff here
});

$j('body').resize(function(){
  //same stuff here
});
```

Maybe I'm just thinking about it the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any selector to another with `.add`

E.g.:

```
$j(window).add('body').resize(function(){
  //same stuff here
});
```

Comment: Upon testing, this seems to be the best solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assign the function to a variable.

```
var handler = function(){
  //stuff here
};

$j(window).resize(handler);

$j('body').resize(handler);
```

Or pass an Array of the DOM elements like this:

```
$j([window, document.body]).resize(function(){
      //stuff here
});
```

Comment: +1  I was surprised this wasnt mentioned before!  Unnamed functions are good to have, but if you are going to use the identical function twice then give it a name, dont declare an unnamed function twice.

Comment: The second answer is good, but before I give you a check, can you answer if I can pass in a mixed array, one with a jQuery object and window?  [window, $j('soandso)]

Comment: @jel402 - For the jQuery object, you would need to extract the DOM element like this: `$j('soandso)[0]` (assuming there's only one element in there).

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsbin.com/imihi3/edit):

```
$("body").add(window).resize(function(){
   //stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about javascript reserverd words. You have list here.

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: Not quite.  I'm working with legacy code, and for some reason they have the same bind, one on the window object (which I do know is a reserved word -- we intentionally call it) and one on the DOM element body.